# How to Copy a text file from one folder to another in VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, text-files, file-copying

I am a newbie programmer, looking for a way to copy a .txt file from one folder to another, can anyone help me?
(Visual Basic 2010 Express)

Comment: I just want to say that your title is way off of what you are asking... What does your question have to do with console applications? Other than that it might be programmed as one. I suggest using a more obvious title next time, like "VB.net copy files". But you are new, so that's ok :) Have fun learning the arts of programming.

Comment: Also, if you want to get into programming, I suggest C#.Net, as it is more familiar to other programming languages, if you ever come across them, but that's rather off topic, and your own decision ;)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is very unclear. Are you writing a console application, and wanting to programmatically copy a text file? Or are you trying to copy and paste a text file from within Visual Studio 2010 VB.Net edition? Please edit your post and clarify your question, and keep in mind we can't see your code or screen (or read your mind); all we have to go by is what you actually tell us. The more clear you can make your question, the better the chances are of getting an answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Look at [System.IO.File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx).

That handles file copy operations for you.

Here's an [example of usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx#Y1124) in VB.Net.